# brewの名前に/（スラッシュ）が含まれているのは特別な意味がありますか？　それとも単なる文字列としてのスラッシュですか？

Tags: sass, homebrew

https://sass-lang.com/install
にインストール方法として

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

と書いてあるのですが、この`/`になにか特別な意味あるのでしょうか？それとも単に文字列としての意味しかないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なかなかこちらで回答がつかなかったので、本家で質問してみました（これがいいことなのか駄目なのかはわかっていません）。

[Is there a special meaning of the / (slash) in the name of the brew?　Or is it just a slash as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533548/is-there-a-special-meaning-of-the-slash-in-the-name-of-the-brew-or-is-it-ju) の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63533627/1979953) によると**意味がある**とのことです。

`GitHubのユーザー名/リポジトリー名/formula` という並びだそうです。
こう書いてしまうと

https://github.com/sass/sass

のことかと思いますが**そうではなくて**、`homebrew-`というプレフィックスをつけるようなので、`sass/sass/sass`が示しているのは

https://github.com/sass/homebrew-sass

になるそうです。

詳しくは [Taps (Third-Party Repositories)](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps) を参照とのこと。